# Chrome flexbox drag and drop redraw bug?

Tags: html, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, flexbox

I'm learning about HTML 5 drag and drop and following this tutorial:

http://html5doctor.com/native-drag-and-drop/

I've got it working, but given that my final intention is to build a small page that will enable to drag and drop images from one div to another, what i'm doing is getting the id of the dragged element, and doing an .appendChild of that element to the div where images can be dropped.

it works fine, but it appears there is a redraw bug on Chrome (on OSX), because as soon as i drag one of the three images to the drop target, it gets added but a ghost of it is still on the original div. sometimes it will go away just by scrolling the page, other times it wont.

If I remove the CSS that makes the origin/target a flexbox, it works fine, no ghosting.

the following is my html/css/js, but i've also put it in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3JznW/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> Drag and Drop </title>
<script src="http://html5demos.com/h5utils.js"></script>
<style>

.fbox
{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#origin {
    width: 600px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: silver;   
}
#origin > div
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: DeepSkyBlue;
}

#drop {
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="origin" class="fbox">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100" id="one" title="one" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x100" id="two" title="two" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/190x100" id="three" title="three" />
    </div>
    <p />
    <div id="drop" class="fbox">
    </div>
</div>

<script>

var dragItems = document.querySelectorAll("img");

for (var i = 0; i < dragItems.length; i++) {

    addEvent(dragItems[i], 'dragstart', function (event) {

        event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", this.id);
        console.log("dragged the id!! " + this.id);

  });
}

var drop = document.querySelector('#drop');

addEvent(drop, 'dragover', cancel);
addEvent(drop, 'dragenter', cancel);

addEvent(drop, 'drop', function (event) {

  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
  }

  var id = event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');

  var elem = document.getElementById(id);

  drop.appendChild(elem);

  return false;
});

function cancel(event) {
  if (event.preventDefault) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  return false;
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

is this problem happening because of my code? or would this be a Chrome bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one replied, and this works just fine in Safari, so it has to be a Chrome (v23.0) bug.

What I did to work around the ghosting of the drag-dropped divs is to fadeIn/fadeOut the origin div and that seems to take care of it.